# Normalize or denormalize varbinary in large table?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I am developing a system involving a 500  GB SQL Server Database.

Query performance and storage complexity are of concern in this scale.

**Question:** The table with most of the records contains a VARBINARY(1500) field which is NULL about 90% of the time. Is it better to normalize this field into a separate table or keep as-is?

Performing actual test would take a lot of time, hoping to save time by asking here first.

Comment: I don't think that would make a difference. I think you should run the `Database Engine Tuning Advisor` as a first step on some of the very large tables, which would provide you with a set of recommendations like creating new indices etc. This could be used as a starting point for optimization.

Comment: Depends. I think you should read carefully [In-Row Data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Pay attention in the `Enabling and Disabling the large value types out of row Option` section. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @shadow: your comment is the answer, thanks! Changing to varbinary(max) and "enabling large value types out of row" makes sense since it means the logical data is more compactly and neatly stored without tiny-blobs interspersed throughout it all -- faster IO for non-SSD physical drives since the data is closer.